# Creating Custom Routes for Multiple Instances of a React Component

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I am still new to the whole routing thing in React, and I am having a hard time creating a route for each instance of a component.

What exactly I am trying to do is, I have an array of paths A, each path also contains an array of paths B relative to A. so when I click on any instance of A, I get a list in elements of B with paths to their data.

The relationship between A and B is akin to:

"Several Apps (B), belong to a certain category (A)".

So far everything I tried has failed miserably, as components on my sub routes failed to render.

A sample of my code can be found on:

https://github.com/edargham/Project-CSC443-Web

My routes are defined only in `App.js`, `categories.js`, and `category.js`

Comment: Really not sure I understand what you're trying to do.. are you trying to dynamically generate your routes based on an array of paths & components (including nested arrays & components)?

Comment: I am not sure I am including nested arrays and components. It is just that when I redirect from a path generated by my previous component, in the I get my new set of paths.